# How many rows contain a specific value using php and mysqli

Tags: php, sql, database, search, mysqli

I have a table "bookings" that looks like

```
bookings
    id      id_class    date                    day         name    
    1       2           2016-03-10 16:00:00     monday      Fredrik
    2       5           2016-03-11 16:00:00     tuesday     Richard
    3       7           2016-03-11 18:00:00     tuesday     Sara
    4       4           2016-03-11 15:00:00     tuesday     Fredrik
```

Then I extract that table using php

```
<?php
    $result = $con->query("select * from bookings");
<?
```

What I want now is a php function that tells me how many rows that contain a specific entry such as "id_class=2" or how many rows contain (name=Fredrik) where the answer should be between 0 and a positive number. Is there a way for this?

Comment: Use a WHERE clause in your SQL query - http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-where/ - and use COUNT - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: If you only want the count run `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE id_class=2"`

Comment: Yeah, but what I want is to make just one query and then using php code to extract what I want without having to make more queries. Your suggestions imply one query per row count, right?

Comment: if you want to do it purely in PHP, it's going to be a lot slower, and a lot more PHP Code, and most people will wonder why you insist on doing it in PHP rather than letting the database do what it's designed too do.... but fetch all your records into a PHP array, use array_filter, and then count; or apply an if test with an incrementing counter as you fetch each row

Answer (score 1):

Use where to get specific condition

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE id_class=2

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE name='Fredrik'
```